# Align text in top middle of any photo/video frame in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to know how to align the text in any sized photo/video frame in the top middle. I understand how to center the text on the x axis in any frame, so how do I make it always be at the top as well?

Heres what I've been doing so far:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "drawtext=font='Impact': text='Test Text': fontcolor=white: borderw=3: fontsize-75: x=(w-tw)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)" output.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By top-middle, I assume you mean horizontally centered and vertically centered within the top-third of the frame. That means the text has to be vertically centered around 1/6th the height. So, `x=(w-tw)/2:y=h/6-th/2`

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for! And just clarifying how would I do the inverse (e.g. Horizontallly and vertically centered at the bottom)?

Comment: That's 1/6th height from the bottom. `y=h-h/6-th/2`